# AC Motor Induction Diagram

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, induction-motor

I have a question with the following information 
"AC motor connected in series to 400v RMS, 40A RMS, pf = 0.707"
It wants me to draw a diagram, my question is:
Can I model the motor as a single phase motor and just draw a motor in series with an inductor and work out the inductance and eventually the capacitance to bring pf unity,
Or does a motor circuit symbol presume an inductance value and can I just label the motor with an inductance?

Cheers

Comment: *"AC motor connected in series to 400v RMS, 40A RMS, pf = 0.707"* doesn't make sense - are you sure you transcribed it correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I mean there is an AC supply and the only component is a motor. The supply is 400v, 40A both RMS

Comment: An AC supply doesn't have an output power factor. A load has a power factor. So it still makes no sense.

Comment: The motor is the only load

Comment: A conventional 400V supply would be 3-phase; so would a conventional motor rated for 400V. So bear that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I model the motor as a single phase motor

One phase of a three-phase motor is usually modeled. You are then working with the line to neutral voltage and the phase current. The electrical power to the circuit, the losses and the electrical power converted to mechanical power are each multiplied by three for the complete motor.

> does a motor circuit symbol presume an inductance value

A three-phase motor circuit symbol would presume a circuit that includes some inductance and resistance. A portion of the resistance is variable to represent the conversion of electrical power to mechanical power. The usual model for one phase is shown below. Note that there is no capacitance in a three-phase induction motor.

[image]

For a situation in which the voltage current and power factor are given, the model must be reduced to an inductor and series resistor for each phase of a wye connected load. The model thus represents to power going into the motor. To determine the mechanical power, you must have the efficiency. The model represents one specific load point.

Comment: Appreciate the in-depth response, so to clarify I could presume a single phase induction motor and simply label one resistor and one inductor and presume it wasn't self starting? If I labeled one R and one X would I need an M symbol anymore or is that deduction implied

Comment: What you need for a diagram would be determined by the context. If the diagram is assumed to be an aid to answering the question you may want to draw the complete 3-phase wye circuit and show how it related to the solution of the problem. Academic questions usually explicitly state whether the problem is about a single-phase or three-phase system. We are assuming 3-phase because a 400 volt single phase motors are not manufactured as far as we who have a great deal of experience are aware. Single-phase motors that are not self-stating are also not made. However, unrealistic questions are asked.